# How to connect to localhost port from android?

Tags: php, qt

I have one problem. I have EasyPHP server on my local computer. I am making program that is connecting to PHP scripts and returns me result to my local PC. Everything works nice I am using 127.0.0.1:8888 address and port. I used 8888 because I needed port 80 for something else. I am connected to my wireless at my place. I put my QT application on my android and change address to 192.168.1.101:8888/page.php and I can't get results back? Anyone knows how can I connect to localhost server trough some other devices which are on same network in my case wireless

EDIT 2:
This is a part to change virtual host:

```
#
# # Use name-based virtual hosting.
# #
# NameVirtualHost *:8888
# 
# #
# # VirtualHost example:
# # Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# # The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# # match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
# #
# <VirtualHost *:8888>
#     ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.127.0.0.1
#     DocumentRoot "${path}/apache/docs/dummy-host.127.0.0.1"
#     ServerName dummy-host.127.0.0.1
#     ServerAlias www.dummy-host.127.0.0.1
#     ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.127.0.0.1-error.log"
#     CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.127.0.0.1-access.log" common
# </VirtualHost>
# 
# <VirtualHost *:8888>
#     ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.127.0.0.1
#     DocumentRoot "${path}/apache/docs/dummy-host2.127.0.0.1"
#     ServerName dummy-host2.127.0.0.1
#     ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.127.0.0.1-error.log"
#     CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.127.0.0.1-access.log" common
# </VirtualHost>
```

anything wrong in it?

Comment: What OS is your local computer running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, EasyPHP access on port 8888 is blocked by your computer's firewall. See [this guide](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/open-a-port-in-windows-7s-firewall/) how to open the firewall to allow remote access to a port on Windows 7.

You also need to check your `Listen` line in httpd.conf, if it's set to `Listen 127.0.0.1:8888` if will only respond to incoming connections from localhost, while `Listen 8888` means it will respond to all incoming requests on that port.

Comment: I have added port and still nothing

Comment: I don't get any error. I have made my app to get data from server at boot time so I only get kicked out of app. And can't start it. I have even changed easyphp config file to Listen 8888 and <VirtualHost *8888> and still nothing.

Comment: @denonth Does the "Listen" line in httpd.conf say "Listen 8888" or "Listen 127.0.0.1:8888"?

Comment: It was Listen `127.0.0.1:8888` but I change it to `Listen 8888` I found on the internet that it should be this way but I am not sure?!

Comment: @denonth Updated my answer, you're correct that it should be `Listen 8888`.

Comment: But I still can't connect to it. I am calling 192.168.1.101:8888 from my app and got kicked out because it can't connect to server. Do you maybe have some idea what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Use `10.0.2.2` as the loopback address.

Comment: where to put that address? Into PHP config file? Or in my application?

Comment: It doesn't seems to be working.. I need to access localhost on my PC from network which has localhost server, IP of that computer is 192.168.1.1:8888

Comment: Do I need to put it like 10.0.2.2:8888 ?